# Easy way to make an Inflater multiple times

Tags: android

I'm programming since 2 weeks an App it's working fine, but I have an problem with creating views multiple times with for-loop.

So I have an ArrayList, which contains the infos of articles for my app (Title, Money and Image).

The loop looks like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

}
```

In this loop I'll add articles with a custom view. I don't want to add them programmatically, because of that I used an inflater. In the inflater I have only my Design. So, RelativeLayout contains an ImageView for image and TextView for Money and Title. They also have an ID.

I add them like this.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article, null);
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(articles.get(0).getTitle());
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.money)).setText(articles.get(0).getMoney());
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(articles.get(0).getImage());
container.addView(view);
```

The problem is, I want to handle the articles by clicking, but it returns always the same view.getId(). I mean clicking first view, should open articles.get(0).getURL(); and etc. with OnClickListener

I use the inflater only for design.

Comment: Why are you not using `ListView` for your list?

Comment: How should I design the article?
EDIT: http://i.gyazo.com/740c055e4e28051cad51e8a66b6016c2.png